# Asterisk Event Device Registration

Tags: python, events, asterisk, asterisk-ari

I am trying to retrieve an event when a device registers an application using ARI. This can be assumed by changing the endpoint state from offline to online. The implementation that I have done in python is:

```
self.client.on_event ('DeviceStateChanged', self.deviceRegistration)
self.client.on_event ('PeerStatusChange', self.deviceRegistration)
self.client.on_event ('EndpointStateChange', self.deviceRegistration)
self.client.on_event ('ContactStatusChange', self.deviceRegistration)
```

and nothing works. Anybody can help ?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a way to solve it. The change of device state has listen by event EndpointStateChange. But before, we must subscribe our application to the stasis. Here the implementation :

```
self.client = ari.connect(.....)    
self.client.applications.subscribe(applicationName="(our stasis name)",eventSource="endpoint:PJSIP")
self.client.on_endpoint_event('EndpointStateChange',self.handleDeviceRegister)
```

where the handleDeviceRegister method are:

```
def handleDeviceRegister(self, channel_obj,ev):                
    if channel_obj.json["state"]=="online":            
        print "channel change from off to online"
```

if anybody get another way please tell me. thanks